# Moving staging wordpress blog to live

Tags: wordpress

[EDIT] I have attempted to re-phrase this question since I feel it is an important one and it has the potential to simplify what may otherwise become a nightmare process. The fact that this has had a few down votes suggests that perhaps the more established "Wordpress professionals" do not quite fathom the fundamental difficulties that novices face and the complex solutions that may otherwise be avoided with a bit of planing.

**My original question:**

```
I have built a WordPress site and theme on a staging domain with the intention of replacing my current domain.

So new site lives at staging.example.com

And I would like to move this to the live URL www.example.com

Ideally with as little downtime as possible.

Is there a simple way to do this?
```

**Background:**

I need to update my Wordpress website to a new look and feel and a general database update etc. I did not wish to hand over admin access to my live site to a developer and therefore created a sub-domain: staging.example.com for them to work on.

On completion, I had to figure out how to get the new site onto the live domain.

I was not sure how to do this:

1. Was there a built in tool to do this?
2. Did I need to clone and import?
3. If so, what clone and import tool to use?
4. etc.

I would imagine this will become a common problem for people as Wordpress matures and the process I eventually followed was incredibly painless however not documented anywhere...

I hope this post helps other people in a similar position to me.

Comment: Just have your live site point to the directory the staging subdomain is in.

Comment: Hi Leland, I should have though of this... actually pretty easy to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be very very simple, although it could have been very complicated.

I am going to write my solution down as it took all of 5 seconds to switch with no hitch what so every.

If you want to build a new template or create a new wordpress website and replace an old one follow these steps:

1. Make sure your current WordPress site is installed in its own directory. If it is not, its pretty simple to do, [follow these instructions.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory)
2. In your hosting account create a subdomain, call it: staging.my-site-name.com. I use Cpanel so I opted for the subdomain to be served from the folder: public_html/staging
3. Build your new WordPress website in the staging domain.

Your directory structure will look something like this:

```
index.php 
wordpress1 
staging
```

4. Once you are happy with your new install, go to settings and edit the domain details to match that of your live settings. Be 100% sure that you are done as once you edit this its a fiddle to change it back...
5. Rename your "staging" folder to something new: "wordpress2" for instance. I do this as I will later be deleting the sub-domain and I don't want it to delete its folder too.
6. Now because you setup your website to be served from its own directory all you need to do in order to switch over to the new site is to edit the index.php file and change the location of the WordPress install from /wordpress1 to /wordpress2.

As soon as you update the location, your site will instantly switch over to the new site.

6. If you are happy, you can remove the sub-domain from your hosting account.

I must be honest, I was thinking of replicating databases and importing templates and this what such a simple way to do the switch. Obviously it would not work if you are invested in your current install of wordpress and are not using it as a simple website with no functionality.

And even if you were, you could quite easily clone it over to the staging site, do your updates there and then switch over as I have outlined.

I will definitely be using this method in the future. There was not even a second of downtime and the only small error was a few image locations needing to be updated which took no more than a minute.

Everyone is happy!

Comment: A search replace tool such as Better-Search-Replace would also be helpful for this method for those pesky image paths that don't migrate over.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress uses explicit file paths so changing your domain will normally break it.

Use a cloning program such as WP-Clone(plugin) or Installatron(server-side program.) These are designed to update your links properly when you move a site.

If you have any non-permalinks that don't migrate properly when you clone your site, you can then use something like Better-Search-Replace(also a plugin) to scan your database for old links and update them.

FYI: Most cloning programs can also be used for managing backups and disaster recovery.

Comment: Thanks for this. Good thinking on the disaster recovery.